# Find the inflection points.

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Find the local extreme points and inflection points of $y=2x^3 + 3x^2 - 12x.$

I know how to find the extreme points, but am confused on the inflection points. We use the second derivative to found those right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Where the second derivative is equal to zero or undefined.

Here we have $$f''(x) = 12 x + 6 = 0$$

Can you take it from here?

You should have also found a local minimum at $x=1$ and a local maximum at $x=-2$.

Comment: I know how to find the 2nd derivative. But don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Solve for $x$ in the expression I wrote. What is the value? That is the point of the inflection. For it's value, substitute that $x$ into the function. Clear?

Comment: yes! thank you!

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti!

Comment: The OP got the answer and did not even have the courtesy to UV! ;-)